# React-native gives 'warning: Functions are not valid as a React child.'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

[image: warnings]

I just started react-native.

When I try to use the createMaterialBottomTabNavigator from 'react-navigatioin-tabs', I got this warning msg. I have no idea which part makes trouble from the code
maybe it's misuse something..

Could you help me out..?

code below..

```
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator
} from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import Home from '../Screens/HomeScreen/Home'
import Maps from '../Screens/HomeScreen/Maps'
import My from '../Screens/HomeScreen/My'
import Subjects from '../Screens/HomeScreen/Subjects'

const BottomTabNavigation = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    Home: { screen: Home },
    Maps: { screen: Maps },
    My: { screen: My },
    Subjects: { screen: Subjects },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
    activeTintColor: '#F44336',
  }
);

export default BottomTabNavigation
```

BottomTabNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  NativeModules,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import styles from '../../Styles/HomeScreen/styles';
import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';

class Home extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarColor: '#3F51B5',
    tabBarIcon: <MaterialIcons
      style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
      name='photo-album'
      color='red'
      size={24}
    />,
  };

  render(){
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
export default Home;
```

Home.js

Comment: i hope following link, solve your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626011/why-am-i-getting-warning-functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child/51626053

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in tabBarIcon, which is defined as a function which returns another function. So you would need to invoke that inner function as well ( **tabBarIcon('photo-album')()** ). And another thing: where is your tintColor variable extracted from?

I would change your code, and do something like this:

```
const tabBarIcon = (name, tintColor) => (
  <MaterialIcons
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'transparent' }}
    name={name}
    color={tintColor}
    size={24}
  />
);

class Home extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    tabBarColor: '#3F51B5',
    tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('photo-album', 'SOME_COLOR'),
    title: 'good job!',
  };
  render() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Thank to your advice. But the problem still shows up.

Answer (score -1):

change `import * as React from 'react';` to

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';


export default class Home extends Component {
}
```

Hope that help