# Why am I getting Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

When I try to call a method which returns the result of the map method, I get the following error `Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render` but I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
renderAlbums() {
        return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{ album.title }</Text>);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                { this.renderAlbums }
            </View>
        );
    }
```

But I the code above I don't see where the problem comes from. But when I try to create a variable in my `render()` method in which a pass my `map()` method,everything works good:

```
render() {
  const c=this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{ album.title }</Text>);
    return (
        <View>
            { c }
        </View>
    );
}
```

I would like to understand why it doesn't work. When I call the render `renderAlbums()` method here `<View>{ this.renderAlbums }</View>`.

And And what seems even weirder to me is that when I try to call the `renderAlbums()` like this `<View>{ this.renderAlbums() }</View>` with parentheses it works.

Comment: you are not executing the function, you're just providing the reference. `this.renderAlbums()` will execute it

Comment: Thank you also,you helped me better ynderstand

Answer (score 67, accepted):

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render

Basically,React expecting the [`React Elements`](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) to render it.

In current script,`this.renderAlbums` is a **function reference** which not returning any [`React Element`](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html).Function itself not react element.So,React unable to render the `this.renderAlbums`.

```
<View>
   { this.renderAlbums }
</View>
```

**correct way:**

```
<View>
   { this.renderAlbums() } //it will return react element which can be rendered.
</View>
```

Comment: I have also encountered the same error with React Native where I'm calling a function which returns another function which returns a component.  For example, in a recent Udacity project I was calling {getMetricMetaInfo('bike').getIcon}  when I should have been calling {getMetricMetaInfo('bike').getIcon()}  Note the second set of parenthesis on the second function to execute the function.

Answer (score 11):

`this.renderAlbums` refers to the actual function itself, whereas `this.renderAlbums()` actually executes the function and thus represents the function's return value.

Answer (score 2):

I think i should share my experience about this error, my code:

```
const PageMakeup = loading ? ThemLoading : (
<div>....</div>
);
```

The problem here is ThemLoading is include in other file, should be `<ThemLoading />`;
And this error is cleared!

About your error: Callback function and return function is diffirent, in your case is the return funtion `this.renderAlbums();`, not `this.renderAlbums`;

Good day!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of pointing to the function return the whole function

```
 return (
            <View>
                { this.renderAlbums() }
            </View>
        );
```