# How react binds events to elements generated by map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When I click `discountKeyboard`,it reported a mistake:

> Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

Here is the code：

```
<View style={[styles.modalStyle, { display: this.state.DiscountVisible ? 'flex' : 'none', position: this.state.DiscountVisible ? 'absolute' : 'relative' }]} >
                    <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignItems: 'flex-end' }} onPress={() => this.setState({ DiscountVisible: false })} >
                        <AntDesign name="close" size={width <= 900 ? 18 : 23} color="black" />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Regular', fontSize: width <= 1024 ? 18 : 22, marginBottom: 10 }} >{translate ? '输入折扣金额' : 'Enter Discount Amount'}</Text>
                    <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Regular', fontSize: width <= 1024 ? 18 : 22, marginBottom: 10 }} >{translate ? '税率' : 'Tax Rate'}: 8.00%</Text>
                    <View>
                        <Text style={[styles.testInputStyle]} >{this.state.discount}</Text>
                        <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }} >
                            <View style={{ width: width <= 1024 ? 194 : 230, flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap' }} >
                                {
                                    this.number.map((item, index) => {
                                        return (
                                            <TouchableOpacity key={index} style={styles.numberStyle} onPress={() => this.discountKeyboard(item)} >
                                                <Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Regular', }}>{item}</Text>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        )
                                    })
                                }
                            </View>
                            <View>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.numberStyle, { height: width <= 1024 ? 121 : 150 }]} onPress={() => this.discountKeyboard('delete')} >
                                    <Feather name="delete" size={20} color="black" />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.numberStyle, { height: width <= 1024 ? 121 : 150 }]} onPress={() => this.discountKeyboard('ok')} >
                                    <AntDesign name="check" size={20} color="black" />
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>



number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, '.', '%']

discountKeyboard = (keyboard) => {
    if (keyboard === 'delete') {
        var p = this.state.discount
        var data = p.substr(0, p.length - 1)
        this.setState({ discount: data })
    } else if (keyboard === 'ok') {
        var op = this.state.discount
        var p = this.state.finalDiscount
        this.setState({
            DiscountVisible: false,
            finalDiscount: parseFloat(this.state.discount),
            total: this.state.total + parseFloat(p) - parseFloat(op)
        })
    } else {
        this.setState({
            discount: preState => preState + keyboard
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the whole file code?

Comment: yes I've increased it

Comment: does this answer your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51626011/why-am-i-getting-warning-functions-are-not-valid-as-a-react-child

Answer (score 0):

I already know the problem

```
this.setState({
        discount: preState => preState + keyboard
})
```

`discount: preState => preState + keyboard` is the wrong way to write it,and `discount: this.state.discount+ keyboard` is right.